# Fully uninstall Stellar from Ledger S

Tags: wallets, ledger

I originally installed Stellar App on my Ledger S and noted my account id.  Unfortunately I didn't record down my secret seed.  I then removed the Stellar App from my Ledger S and then again re-installed the Stellar App to generate new set of public and secret keys.  Problem I am having is that the Ledger is still recognising the original account id I was issued.  This is no help as I don't have the secret seed which goes with this address.

Any idea how to get the Ledger S to recognise a new account id?

Answer (score 1):

To get a new address with the Ledger without doing custom work, you'll need to reset the ledger itself (which is probably not something you want to do).

When you reinstall apps, it will always generate that from some master private key that is used to regenerate same addresses for the different apps. Resetting the ledger will reset this master private key.

If what you want to do is control multiple addresses with your ledger, make your address a signer or the only signer of other Stellar addresses. See https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with resetting the device itself if the accounts generated from that seed are all empty. Once you have no accounts managed by the device with balances, you can reset the device and safely record the new seed.